# Mysql Left join rotate 90° table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a select statement and use virtual columns, based on a different table with a key value system.

Lets say I have a common table for all users named `media`

Media is like this :

```
id | cust_id | filename | hidden
55   2         lorem.jpg  0
```

but some customers need additional rows so I have a second table with :

```
media_id | cust_id | rowname | value
55         2         author    John Doe
55         2         release   2015-10-10
55         2         price     42
```

I'd like to recreate a table where I can search inside these virtual values
like

```
select * from media ..magical join later.. WHERE author = "John Doe";
```

How is that possible? Am I missing some convenient alternative way of having different rows for different users with a common main table?

I'd like to avoid storing JSON data in one column as this would be hard to select data in sql, but that's the only solution I have at the moment (selecting all and parsing rows in app/web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magical Join! I love it. Must-have feature for the next release of MySQL.  :-)

In the meantime, here's what you do.

```
SELECT m.id, 
       m.cust_id,
       a.value   AS author,
       r.value   AS release,
       p.value   AS price, 
       m.filename,
       m.hidden
  FROM media m
  LEFT JOIN other_table a ON m.id = a.id AND a.rowname = 'author'
  LEFT JOIN other_table p ON m.id = p.id AND p.rowname = 'price'
  LEFT JOIN other_table r ON m.id = r.id AND r.rowname = 'release'
```

This use of a LEFT JOIN for each distinct attribute in your `other_table` (which you might call an `attributes` table or a `metadata` table) will allow your query to work even when some of your original rows don't have some of the metadata items.

Then if you need to filter or order on some of these items, you wrap this query in an outer query.  For example.

```
 SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT m.id, 
            m.cust_id,
            a.value   AS author,
            r.value   AS release,
            p.value   AS price, 
            m.filename,
            m.hidden
       FROM media m
       LEFT JOIN other_table a ON m.id = a.id AND a.rowname = 'author'
       LEFT JOIN other_table p ON m.id = p.id AND p.rowname = 'price'
       LEFT JOIN other_table r ON m.id = r.id AND r.rowname = 'release'
    ) all
 WHERE release >= '2010-01-01'
 ORDER BY author
```

It happens, for what it's worth, that WordPress uses this strategy to store arbitrary information in its `wp_postmeta` table.

Comment: If WP uses this, then I'm probably on the right track for the same metadata storage system! Thanks for the info